# Error importing files with BlackBerry Desktop Manager

Tags: blackberry

I am packaging a BlackBerry application for desktop installation (i.e., .ALX and .COD files). However, I am having some problems:

I am seeing an error "There was an error importing files. No additional application can be found. Your file might contain applications that already exist in the application list, are not compatible for your device, or have errors".

What could be causing the problem?

Please look at to the image

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the .ALX file in an editor to make sure that it is pointing to your .COD file's correct location?

Comment: i changed to "Over-the-air (OTA)" way of installation its working fine ,thnks for the suggestion

Comment: Please add this as a reply and mark it as the solution. This will be helpful for others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error While Deploying BlackBerry Application in to Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051814/error-while-deploying-blackberry-application-in-to-device)