# Error While Deploying BlackBerry Application in to Device

Tags: blackberry

When I am trying to deploy the BlackBerry Application's .cod file in to real device 9300 curve, it is showing me following error message.

[image]

What could be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your alx file on directives which control target device OS version.

This error occurs when device operating system is older than SDK you have used to compile the application. I.e you have device with OS 5.0 and are trying to install app compiled with SDK 6.0

Device OS version must be equal or bigger than SDK version you have used to compile the application.